# Form submission via ajax rails 2 to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading my ruby on rails application from rails `2.3.14` to rails `3.2.6`. In my ajax form submission, i am getting following errors.

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form :

```
<%= token_tag nil %>
```